# Oracle: force RR year format unexpectedly

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, type-conversion

I have a DATE field in a Oracle table.
Populate script for this field is like this:

```
TO_DATE('2013-01-02 10:15:51', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

But in my SQL Developer editor, go to Table -> Data section for this table and date looks like *02/01/13*

Then, in SQL Developer SQL sheet, in a simple query, I want to force year to show four digits with the classic TO_DATE conversion:

```
TO_DATE(field, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date_field
```

and it's also showning *02/01/13*

Finally, the worst of all is in application, where I'm trying to force four digit again, and converting date with java SimpleDateFormat class, with dd/MM/yyyy pattern.
The date in application is ***02/01/0013***

If I edit that value and set *02/01/2013*, SQL Developer generates this update sentence

```
TO_DATE('02/01/2013', 'DD/MM/RR')
```

and I don't understand why is trying to convert to RR year format.

So, what's happening? Is some session or database parameter?

Any help would be very appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be nice if u'd write your SQL Developer version. And its not database related, but merely settings of SQL Developer.

This behavior customizable in preferences (Tools/Preferences): DATABASE/NLS/Date Format.
By default it set to DD.MM.RR, change it to the one you like.

Comment: thank you for your idea. It's in SQLDeveloper, but it isn't from my application, but you put me on the way to fix it. I have to set that parameter with a trigger after logon, and finally it works.

Answer (score 1):

Open Tools-Preferences and NLS.[image]

Comment: thank you for your idea. It's in SQLDeveloper, but it isn't from my application, but you put me on the way to fix it. I have to set that parameter with a trigger after logon, and finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think DD/MM/RR is the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the oracle database. you can query it out to see exactly.

Your issue is not how the data is store but how you retrieve it.

Try to use TO_CHAR() and a mask format with mm:ss to get the exact time stamp and see if gets the correct date

Comment: thank you for your answer, but TO_CHAR() does not work for me. Parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT must be changed.